# Delete old columns from table using hook update

Tags: 7, updating

I need to delete some old columns of existing table. How to do it using `hook_update` or Is there some other way to delete old columns in `.install` file .

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can use function [db_drop_field()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_drop_field/7)

```
/**
 * Implements hook_update_N().
 */
function mymodule_update_7001() {
  db_drop_field('my_table', 'my_column');
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: Yeah, I updated my post